# SharpDX - fxc.exe error when compiling hlsl file

Tags: c#, directx, hlsl, vertex-shader, sharpdx

I'am starting to learn SharpDX and Holographic template for C#.

While compiling project I have error at compilation of shader file.

```
var vertexShaderByteCode = ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile("Content/Shaders/VertexSharderShared.hlsl", "VS", "vs_5_0", ShaderFlags.Debug);
```

fxc.exe exited with code 1.

In the sample they use some .cso file while loading shader into byte code:
[code img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rr36k.png)

As I don't really understand where that .cso comes from and what Vprt is, I prefer loading hlsl file directly. I'm using SharpDX 3.0.2, SharpDX.Direct3D11 3.0.2 and SharpDX.D3DCompiler 3.0.2.

Thanks!

Comment: Those are compiled shaders. ``fxc`` is a HLSL compiler and you can execute it via command line too. What version of VS are you using? VS should automatically compile your shaders when compiling your project

Comment: @Asesh Thanks for your response. I'm using VS2017 and testing on Hololens emulator. I've just understood that I must specify location to compiled shaders (.cso files). I've tempted so many different URI and finally found the right one but it always return empty to bytecode value of my variable (vertexShaderByteCode)

Comment: Well, if you look at this source code: https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.D3DCompiler/ShaderBytecode.cs ``ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile:  Compiles a shader or effect from a file on disk`` so you are using wrong method because cso is already a compiled shader

Comment: Also ``CompilationResult`` is the return value of ``ShaderBytecode.CompileFromFile``, not shader byte code

Comment: There's probably something wrong in your shader: ``Content/Shaders/VertexSharderShared.hlsl``. You should post it's source code here

Comment: @Asesh I don't think it's the code source, it's a sample shader given by Microsoft in Holographic temple that I never touched. Also, when I tried to compile the file by ReadDataAsync() it worked. When I use method CompileFromFile from SharpDX, it gets the file but return vertexShaderByteCode.ByteCode = empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSO files need to be loaded then the relevant shader created.  Below is an example of a function I use to load the shader.  Please note, that you should hold onto the byte code as well as the vertex shader in this example.

The Helper function is my cross uwp/mfc wrapper, but it basically returns the file in a datastream in memory.

The CSO file is byte code, you need to attach it to the correct Sharpdx.Direct3D11 shader class.

The bytecode is also used to reference the semantic interface (for Vertex buffers only).  once you have created that, your draw call can match the data against the GPU register that it is associated to.   But the code below at least will load your CSO file in and create the vertexshader.

goodluck.

```
         using (Stream fileStream = Helper.GetFileStream(a_fileName, a_filePath))
        {
            a_byteCode = new D3DCompiler.ShaderBytecode(fileStream);

            if (a_byteCode != null)
            {
                a_child = new D3D11.VertexShader(a_device, a_byteCode)
                {
                    DebugName = "a_fileName"
                };
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to load file: " + a_fileName);
            }

        }
```

Comment: yes that's pretty similar to the schema used in holographic template. I didn't understand at the time that the hlsl files would be compiled into .cso at the same time we compiled the project. Thank you!